# Amazon iOS SDK S3 Upload Multipart Request Fails with Mysterious URL

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

My application is implementing a technique described [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0006282245644577) to allow multipart file uploads to occur over 3G connections from the iPhone. I have managed to plug a delegate into the action as well, and I can monitor the upload progress. However, after upload is complete the file simply isn't there.

Digging deeper, I have discovered what appears to be a malformed URL in the SDK. Here's the relevant code:

```
__strong AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:kS3Access withSecretKey:kS3Secret];
s3.timeout = 240;

s3ResponseHandler = [[S3ResponseHandler alloc] init];

S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest *initReq = [[S3InitiateMultipartUploadRequest alloc] initWithKey:[filePath lastPathComponent] inBucket:kS3Bucket];
```

The initReq object inherits, ultimately, from S3Request, which has a url property. In the following lines I log the value of my [filePath lastPathComponent] and that url property:

```
NSLog(@"filePath lastComp: %@", [filePath lastPathComponent]);
NSLog(@"initReq URL: %@", [initReq url]);
```

The results:

```
filePath lastComp: filename.ext
initReq URL: https://<bucketname>.(null)/filename.ext
```

I believe the URL should be https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com, rather than (null).

If this is the URL that the SDK is using to push my upload, then it's clearly not going to work! Can anyone suggest what troubleshooting steps I might take to further diagnose this issue and a workaround? It almost feels like a bug in the SDK, but I trust myself much less than that.

I'm using the current (as of this writing) 1.3.0 version of the SDK.

Comment: hi @Aaron Vegh plz tell me how can i get progress event

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out, thanks to Amazon AWS support. Full post is [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=350809&#350809), but here's the nut for posterity.

Turns out that when you support multipart upload, the file must be greater than 5MB, *except for the last part*. I assumed the first part could be the last part as well. So now I have a simple test statement: files smaller than 5MB will be uploaded using the "Single Put Object Request" (as per the link in my question), whereas the larger files will go multipart. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see you have already found your answer, however I want to offer some additional insight for others getting their AWS chops together.

[This post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads) details one process for uploads and tracking them. It also contains some insight on how S3TransferManager handles threads. Relevantly, AWS offers two important ways to post data to s3: `upload:` and `putObjectRequest:`. The method `upload:` offers the ability to upload multiple files/requests without halting your UI. The method `getObjectRequest:` could halt your UI and prevent another request until the transfer is done.

Again just to add additional insight on methodology for requests and the way the S3TransferManager handles threads.